# 22.04 jelly fish update not showing in ubuntu 20.04 in september 2022, Why?

Tags: upgrade, updates

Why am I not getting the jellyfish update when LTS 22.04 is out there like 5 months ago.
All i get is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoETK.png)

Comment: Before anything else check Software & Updates > Updates

Answer (score 0):

**Execute the below commands:**

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

At the prompt, type y and press Enter to All Step

When successful update, checking the version of Ubuntu.

```
lsb_release -a
```